# Ploting implicit function in closeness of a point

Tags: matlab, plot, implicit, curve

I'm given an implicit function:
`sin(x)*tan(x)-(y^2-3)*ln(2*y+3)=0`

My task is to:

- plot a curve of this function in closeness of a point `T(0,√3)`
- find out how many unconnected components are there in x∈[-1.7, 1.7], y∈[-2, 2]

My attempt:

First I thought to just plot out the function curve using the `ezplot` on demanded area like so: `ezplot('sin(x)*tan(x)-(y^2-3)*log(2*y+3)',[-1.7, 1.7, -2, 2])`. But the result I get is very strange. I get two half’s of ellipse facing away from each other. I can only assume that I’ve used function `ezplot` the wrong way. Please help.

Comment: What do you expect instead?

Comment: I don't know how to answer the second question. Are there two unconnected components (bottom half of ellipse)?

Comment: @Daniel the task seems too easy to be true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ezplot` commant is quite good, but other than that you could also try

```
[x,y]=meshgrid(-1.7:0.01:1.7, -2:0.01:2);
contour(x,y,sin(x).*tan(x)-(y.^2-3).*log(2*y+3),[0,0]);
```

instead.

Comment: I would like to do it like you suggested but first I've got the error »Input arguments for contour must be real«. I fixed it like this `contour(X,Y, real(z(X,Y)) ,[0,0],'r') `, but the result is not the same as in `ezplot `. Now I have many additional curves on figure. Also how can I show 20 points in this order: start at point ` (0,sqrt(3)) `, 10 points `x+=0.1`, 10 points `y+=0.1`?

Comment: I think the problem is that you try to use `log` on negative numbers. Generally the syntax for ranges is: a:b:c where a,b are start and end values, and b is the step size.